# Lead default record type for all profiles

Tags: profile, record-type, leads

i want to extract(view) the lead default record type assigned for all profiles

doing this manually is very tiring[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's how the files are organized. You could choose to download them offline with [Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/developer-centers/developer-experience) (try `sfdx force:source:retrieve -u usernameOrAlias -m Profile,RecordType,CustomObject:Lead`), but you'd still need a way to look at all the profiles or extract the values somehow.

For example, you could use [VS Code's](https://code.visualstudio.com/) "Search in Files" with "Regular Expression", and use something like:

```
<recordTypeVisibilities>
    <default>true</default>
    <recordType>Lead.*</recordType>
```

And from there, choose "Open in Editor":

[image: Open in Editor view]

This gives you a full list of values and their default. If no default is set, it is the `--Master--` record type.

I don't have any Lead examples to show in my org, so I used Opportunity, instead, but the principle holds.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox , i have another question please, how i can get (view) picklist values based on record type ?

Comment: @HichamHdidou You'll find the objects/ObjectName/recordTypes folder has all the record types, with their configured picklist values.